# Find distinct/unique people without a birthday or have a birthday earlier than 3/1/1963

Tags: elasticsearch

We have some employees and needed to find those we haven't entered their birthday or are born before 3/1/1963:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
           "bool": { 
              "must_not": [{ "exists": { "field": "birthday" } }]
           }
        },
        {
           "bool": {
              "filter": [{ "range": {"birthday": { "lte": 19630301 }} }]
           }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

We now need to get distinct names...we only want 1 Jason or 1 Susan, etc. How do we apply a distinct filter to the "name" field while still filtering for the birthday as above? I've tried:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "birthday"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "birthday": {
                    "lte": 19630301
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "uniq_gender": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 25
}
```

but just get results with duplicate Jasons and Susans. At the bottom it will show me that there are 10 Susans and 12 Jasons. Not sure how to get unique ones.

EDIT:

My mapping is very simple. The name field doesn't need to be keyword...can be text or anything else as it is just a field that just gets returned in the query.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "birthdays": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "birthday": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "basic_date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you update the results of the query along with mapping for `name`?

Comment: @ChandraPraneethN added my mapping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your mapping, I'm guessing that your field `name` is not analyzed and able to be used on terms aggregation properly.

I suggest you,  use filtered aggregation:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "filtered_employes": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "birthday"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "birthday": {
                  "lte": 19630301
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filtered_employes_by_name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In other hand your query is not correct your applying a `should` bool filter. Change it by `must` and the aggregation will return only results from employes with (missing birthday) and (born before date).

Comment: I am still getting duplicate names.

Comment: Writing this query in SQL it's like:
`SELECT name FROM employes WHERE birthday != NULL and birthday <= 19630301 GROUP BY (name)`

Could you add the response you're getting? Because this query should be suffice to get employes grouped by name.

Comment: It should be an OR statement, not AND. Also, if you take out the "aggs" section it seems to be giving the exact same results and no grouping by name is taking place.

Comment: Remember that results of aggregation aren't in `hits` instead they're inside `buckets` response.

Comment: Forgot about that....it is coming up empty though. Turns out I oversimplified my example and left out some critical info. I will accept this and just do another question.